# Ubuntu 16.04 very laggy (because of AMD?) possible to downgrade?

Tags: 16.04, downgrade

Sorry I am a complete beginner to this. I was having a lot of problems with windows 10 so I decided to give linux a go.

I downloaded Ubuntu 14, and ran it as a trial. It worked very well, very quickly (except for initial boot). I decided OK and went to install v16.04 by clicking the link on the launcher. I installed it alongside Windows 10.

After installing 16 it started running much more slowly. Videos are laggy, search is laggy, opening and closing windows etc was also quite laggy.

I decided to do a clean install and replace windows 10 completely thinking maybe I just messed up by not giving it a big enough partition on my hard drive to run. I have a 1 TB hard drive with AMD A8. After installing it clean I still had the same lag problem though, and it crashes quite often if I open too many browser windows (4) for example. I read that maybe this is because it doesn't support AMD? Is there a way to downgrade to 14 which seemed to work OK? Or could there be another reason? I don't mind losing whatever I have, I only installed skype/VLC/codecs so far.

Sorry for the long post, wanted to be as clear as possible! Hope somebody can help.

Thanks!

Comment: You will find lots of of different flavours for 14.04  releases.ubuntu.com/trusty. This assumes that you have another machine to burn the iso on : http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/  If you don't mind stating from scratch, you can burn both a 14.04 and a 16.04  before hand and then experiment with each one.

Comment: Thanks, weirdly I'm pretty sure that the version I had on the USB that I used to install was v14.04, but it installed v16.04 anyway. Maybe I'm confused though, I'll check when I get home!

Comment: I have created a usb boot of ubuntu 15.10 but I don't get how to boot from this. When I restart the computer and hold shift to go to the grub menu, theres no option to boot from the usb

Comment: That grub menu is on your hard disk. Boot device options are normally in the BIOS. If your machine can't boot from a USB, burn a DVD instead.

Comment: Thanks Nick, found it in the end! In case anyone else is stuck like I was, I had to hold F10 while starting the computer which took me to the BIOS menu and then put boot from USB as the preferred choice.

Unfortunately however downgrading to 14 or 15 hasn't helped either, the computer still crashes every few minutes and I have to restart and it is extremely slow. Guess I'll have to go back to windows! Not sure why, my computer should easily run it.